# Use Prototype Cell From Another View Controller

Tags: uitableview, xcode5, uistoryboard

I want to use the same table view cell layout in several storyboard scenes.  Can I design the prototype cell in one of the scenes and somehow access it (i.e. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier) in another table view controller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, but you can copy the prototype cell from source table view to destination one inside storyboard and you can easily reuse it.

Comment: That is what I have been doing. Just wanted to know if this was possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can design your prototype cell in a `.xib` file and import that into multiple `UITableViewController` subclasses. Just make sure to keep the identifier in synch between your references in code and your prototype cell.

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "your_file_name", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "your_cell_identifier")
        // ... 
    }

}
```

Same applies to custom UICollectionViewCell prototypes and their use in `UICollectionView` subclasses.