# Can table cell selection segues be configured within storyboard interface builder when using XIBs?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib, uistoryboardsegue

I'm designing a `UITableView` in a storyboard. Initially, I was designing the prototype cells within the storyboard; now I've moved to using a XIB for the cell design, so I can reuse it in multiple tables. When the cells were designed within the storyboard, my cell selection segues were configured in the storyboard also. Now that I am using a XIB, the cell selection segues are not triggered when I select a cell.

Is there a way of configuring the selection segues of XIB-designed cells within the interface builder?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible. But you can use the cell prototyped in Storyboard within different TableViews (by reuseIdentifier).

Comment: just use a little code to call the segue programatically, xib to storyboard connection is not possible

Comment: I want to do it in the storyboard because of the handy "Preview and Commit Segues" checkbox (ie peek and pop); one less thing to write. I didn't know you could reuse prototype cells in different tables, I'll check that out!

Comment: I haven't managed to reuse a prototype cell in different table views. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921924/use-prototype-cell-from-another-view-controller) has answers saying it is not possible. I guess I will just have to use the XIB and invoke the segue (and push and pop) manually.